# If pass more then 1 link jquery mobile popup won't open

Tags: jquery-mobile

After link passing jquery mobile automatically downloading content from link and shows that downloaded page by adding `ui-page-active` class to the div block with `data-role="page"` while from another div with `data-role="page"` this class is removing. So I have 2 divs with `data-role="page"` on one page simultaneously and each contain the same popup block so I think for this reason it's not opening. So what should I do to solve this?

Sorry for my bad English and thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who encountered with the same problem, you need to read [that](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/popup-outside-multipage/#&ui-state=dialog) I think it should help.